# How to simulate let expressions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming, let

Consider the following implementation of [`take`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:take):

```js
const take = (n, [x, ...xs]) =>
    n === 0 || x === undefined ?
    [] : [x, ...take(n - 1, xs)];

console.log(take(7, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(take(3, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])); // [1, 2, 3]
console.log(take(1, [undefined, 1]));  // []
```

As you can see, it doesn't work for arrays with `undefined` because `x === undefined` is not the best way to test whether an array is empty. The following code fixes this problem:

```js
const take = (n, xs) =>
    n === 0 || xs.length === 0 ?
    [] : [xs[0], ...take(n - 1, xs.slice(1))];

console.log(take(7, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(take(3, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])); // [1, 2, 3]
console.log(take(1, [undefined, 1]));  // [undefined]
```

However, writing `xs[0]` and `xs.slice(1)` isn't as elegant. In addition, it's problematic if you need to use them multiple times. Either you'll have to duplicate code and do unnecessary extra work, or you'll have to create a block scope, define constants and use the return keyword.

The best solution would be to use a [let expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_expression). Unfortunately, JavaScript doesn't have them. So, how to simulate let expressions in JavaScript?

Comment: `undefined` is a real value, but not part of a sparse array by using it. a real sparse array looks like `[, 1]`.

Comment: @NinaScholz Ah, I see. I was under the impression that `[, 1]` and `[undefined, 1]` were equivalent but apparently it's not so. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: An array `take` function using `slice` is definitely weird, yes :-)

Comment: Why not simply `const take = (n, xs) => xs.slice(0, n)` ?

Comment: @AramilRey Because that was an example I fabricated for this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Lisp, a [let expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_expression) is just syntactic sugar for a left-left lambda (i.e. an [immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)). For example, consider:

```lisp
(let ([x 1]
      [y 2])
  (+ x y))

; This is syntactic sugar for:

((lambda (x y)
    (+ x y))
  1 2)
```

In ES6, we can use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) to create an IIFE that looks like a let expression as follows:

```js
const z = ((x = 1, y = 2) => x + y)();

console.log(z);
```

Using this hack, we can define `take` as follows:

```js
const take = (n, xxs) =>
    n === 0 || xxs.length === 0 ?
    [] : (([x, ...xs] = xxs) => [x, ...take(n - 1, xs)])();

console.log(take(7, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(take(3, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])); // [1, 2, 3]
console.log(take(1, [undefined, 1]));  // [undefined]
```

However, it would be best to use statements instead of expressions here.

```js
const take = (n, xxs) => {
  if (n === 0 || xxs.length === 0) return [];
  const [x, ...xs] = xxs;
  return [x, ...take(n - 1, xs)];
};

console.log(take(7, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(take(3, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])); // [1, 2, 3]
console.log(take(1, [undefined, 1]));  // [undefined]
```

Comment: Using default parameter values is definitely what I would consider a hack :-)

Comment: Could as well pass the value(s) as arguments instead of using default params, no?

Comment: @FelixKling Indeed. However, it just looks more like a let expression when you use default parameters.

Comment: A hack is just an euphemism for incorrect use of the language. Instead, you should reduce the need for `let` expressions in JS by introducing memoization, for instance.

Comment: @ftor I agree, hacks should be kept to a minimum. However, I fail to see how memoization would help reduce the need for let expressions.

Comment: Because you don't need to assign the result of a memoized function to a variable, but only have to pass the same argument. This will at least cover some of the use cases of let expressions, right?

Comment: @ftor No. They are used for very different things.

Comment: @Bergi It's quite hacky, but I love it because it's much more cleaner than 
`(() => {const x = 1; const y = 2; return x + y;})()`

Comment: IMO it's actually pretty readable. Arrow IIFEs(e.g. `(() => 0)()`) are already pretty common in js, so `((a=1, b=2) => a+b))()` reads pretty easily as "let a=1 and b=2 return a+b". Definitely better than `((a, b) => a+b)(1, 2)`. Although I kind of wish that `let` & `const` could be used in expressions and would evaluate to their right hand side the same way that implicit global declaration works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an IIFE just use a normal function with a proper name to make things more explicit:

```js
const _let = f =>
  f();

const collateBy = f => xs =>
  xs.reduce((m, x) =>
    _let((r = f(x), ys = m.get(r) || []) =>
      m.set(r, (ys.push(x), ys))), new Map());

const includes = t => s =>
  s.includes(t);

xs = ["Dev", "Jeff", "Kalib", "Amy", "Gemma"];

const collation = collateBy(includes("e")) (xs);

console.log(collation.get(true));
console.log(collation.get(false));
```