# JavaScript (es6) haskel where alternative

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

In Haskell you can create where condition for temporary variables like this:

```
f x
  | cond1 x   = a
  | cond2 x   = g a
  | otherwise = f (h x a)
  where
    a = w x
```

Is it possible to create this in javascript but with expression not statements.

For example:

```
let a = 10;
let b = a + 20;

return a + b
```

This is just simple example which doesn't require temporary variables but it was just example.

The below example is with statements - but I wonder if there is good alternative with expression.

Ramdajs can be used if it  appropriate.

Thanks

Comment: `where` is always local to a function, and sure you can easily put a declaration inside a function

Comment: "*The below example is with statements*" - what example are you referring to?

Comment: What's the problem with using statements?

Comment: Notice that it's a statement in Haskell as well, not an expression (`let a = w x in …`)

Comment: You cannot pass it in another function directly

Comment: Why would you want to pass it to another function?

Comment: If i have R.[function](R.{function}, R.{function})((a,b) => {code}) - in the place of code I want to put expression because it's less code and return directly instead of creating {let a =10,let b=20;code; return result }

Comment: I still fail to see how using statements would be undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

IIFEs would work:

```
  (a => (b => a + b)(a + 20))(10)
```

Comment: Or more legibly, `((a = 10, b = a + 20) => a + b)()`.

Comment: Thanks, it works but i find it hard to read if i have 3, 4 variables, i didn't find anything better anyway

Comment: @AaditMShah Don't abuse default initialisers for that

Comment: @Bergi How about `(() => { const a = 10; const b = a + 20; return a + b; })()` then?

Comment: It's very long as code, I want something easy like in haskell but maybe it doesn't exists in js

Comment: @user2693928 A long piece of code does not imply that it's not easy.

Comment: @aadit that ain't expressions only.

Comment: @JonasWilms Sure, but the entire thing is an expression. I don't understand the fascination with everything being an expression anyway. In fact, as Bergi pointed out the `where` clause in Haskell is also not an expression.

Comment: IMHO, readability trumps "everything should be an expression".

Comment: "What you ask for is what you get" ... :)

Comment: @AaditMShah I like that IIFE with `const` declarations much better, thanks :-)

Comment: @AaditMShah Also remember [How to simulate let expressions in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51407631/1048572) :-)

Comment: @Bergi Ahaha. Yes, I do. I was really naive last year. =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript's default parameters in a creative way:

```js
const _let = f => f();

const main = _let((a = 10, b = a + 20) =>
  a + b);

console.log(main);
```

Please note that default parameters aren't evaluated recursively, i.e. the left parameter cannot depend on the right one.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing is a lambda / arrow function, invoked on spot.

Example from [Haskell: Where vs. Let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362328/haskell-where-vs-let) (because I do not know Haskell)

> ```
> f x y  |  y>z           =  ...
>        |  y==z          =  ...
>        |  y<z           =  ...
>      where z = x*x
> ```

Could be something like

```js
((x,y)=>{
  let z=x*x;
  if(y>z){console.log("y>z");}
  else if(y==z){console.log("y==z");}
  else /*if(y<z)*/{console.log("y<z");}
})(10,20);
```

Well, if I understand correctly that `f x y | ...` is some kind of a switch statement with predicates (which do not really convert to the `switch` of JS)

Comment: Thanks, I will write it with statements, that way is many characters and hard to read