# Is there any way to emulate inline let expressions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a compiler from a functional language to JavaScript. Since my language is based on expressions, it is natural to compile it to a JavaScript expression too. The problem is that when compiling `let` expressions, we need the ability to declare and assign variables "inline". For example:

```
function foo(x) {
  return (let y = x * x; y);
}
```

This code, obviously, doesn't work since we can't use `let` inside expressions. One solution would be to wrap everything inside a lambda:

```
function foo(x) {
  return (()=>{let y = x*x; return y})();
}
```

But this has a significant runtime cost in some cases. The other alternative would be to just adjust the compiler to produce statements instead of expressions, but this would be a non-trivial change and I'd rather avoid it if possible.

Is there any way to declare and assign local variables to JavaScript as an expression rather than a statement that has no extra runtime costs?

Comment: A true lambda version would be `return (y => y)(x * x);` This is probably also much easier to postprocess for simplification.

Comment: why wouldn't it just be `function foo (x) { return x*x }`

Comment: This is a great alternative, but also has significant runtime costs, sadly, specially in very numeric code. I'm not sure why JS runtimes can't optimize it away as it is just a single inline step, but that's how it is.

Comment: [How to simulate let expressions in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51407631/1048572)

Comment: @epascarello consider a function like `pow2(x) { return (let y = pow2(x-1); x === 0 ? 1 : y + y); }`. If we just removed the `let` as you suggest, i would become `pow2(x) { return x === 0 ? 1 : pow2(x-1) + pow2(x-1); }`. Notice that the first function is `O(n)`, and the second is `O(2^n)`. Doing that could result in exponential slowdowns in some cases.

Comment: @Bergi interesting thread but the suggested solutions are my examples of incorrect solutions (since the extra lambda makes the program slower in most modern runtimes).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to simulate let expressions in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51407631/how-to-simulate-let-expressions-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not.

You should consider using the standard lambda calculus technique where `let x = … in …` is equivalent to `(x => …)(…)`. Then have another pass of your compiler remove the superfluous function expressions, introducing statements where possible.

An alternative might be to use the `do { let x = …; … }` syntax from the [*do expressions* proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-do-expressions), allowing you to use [their transpiler plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-do-expressions) for generating function-less code.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid creating new variables and just return the value directly:

```
function foo(x) {
  return  x * x;
}
```

But if you really need to inline a let, this should work:

```
const foo = (x) => {let y=x*x;return y;}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to declare and assign local variables to JavaScript as an expression rather than a statement that has no extra runtime costs?

Not really, but you can use [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) with the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). I know, I know, `eval()` is evil, but it's the only way to declare **local** variables in an expression (AFAIK), though I wouldn't recommend it because engines don't optimize `eval()` calls.

```js
function foo(x) {
  return (eval("var y"), y = x * x, y);
}
```

**Edit:** As [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) pointed out, using `let` makes the variable local to the code inside executed using `eval()`, causing `y = x * x` to create a global variable named `y`. `var` should be used instead.

Comment: Hey, this *is* an interesting solution that i didn't think of. Of course this doesn't solve the problem as an extra function call would be massively faster than invoking `eval` on each `let`, but you get the points for the creativity.

Comment: Actually, this does declare a global variable (for some reason that I don't quite understand yet), and it definitely will fail in strict mode where `let`-declared variables are subject to a local scope inside the `eval`ed expression.

Comment: @Bergi I found the problem and edited my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @D.Pardal Oh, of course, it's not the `let y` getting evaled globally that creates the global variable but rather the `y = …` assignment in sloppy mode. Thanks for the update. Notice however that even `var` doesn't work in strict mode.