# Can I define a local scope while defining a variable/const in JavaScript or TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, syntax, scope

I use mostly F# and recently I've started exploring the World of JavaScript.

In F# (and many other languages) it is possible to create local scopes while defining a binding, e.g.

```ml
// F# code
let myValue =
  let internalValue = 1
  internalValue + 5
```

In this example `myValue` is assigned a value of `6`, while `internalValue` remains invisible outside of the inner scope.

I wonder if I can do something like this in JavaScript or TypeScript.
For now the closest thing I've found so far is to define a lambda and call it immediately like this:

```js
// JS Code
const myValue = (() => {
  const internalValue = 1;
  return internalValue + 5; 
})();
```

<s>This works, but doesn't look pretty. Is there anything better?</s>

I believe this feature has it's own name, but I don't know what it is therefore I couldn't find the answer on SO.

##### EDIT - question clarified after a piece of feedback

This works as expected, but I wonder if the same thing can be achieved without creating the lambda?

Comment: ① The term is *immediately invoked function expression* (IIFE).  Knowing that you might want to search and then let us know if you find something we can use as a duplicate target for your question. ② Assuming the question remains, "This works, but doesn't look pretty. Is there anything better?" seems like an opinion question.  Could you please [edit] to rephrase this so that it's possible to identify an objectively correct answer? By what metric shall we judge if something is "better" here?  Apparently it's "pretty", but that seems very subjective (eyes of beholders and whatnot).

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the hint. I'll rephrase it now to avoid doubts and will search for a duplicate. If I find it, I'll close this question.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/51407631/2887218 ?

Comment: Yes, That's it. Thanks. How do I close my question as a duplicate? Shall I just hit the "Close" button?

Comment: Yes, and then select "duplicate" as the reason, and it asks for the target. I've already done this, though, since you agree that it's suitable.  (And please don't feel like you should delete the question; duplicates serve a purpose of providing more useful search results)

Comment: Ha, I'm not a moderator, although I apparently have enough Stack Overflow TypeScript Fun Points™ for it to automatically close things as duplicates when I vote for that. But yeah, I almost never downvote unless there's a major problem that the author isn't willing to address (e.g., blatantly incorrect answer, etc.)

Comment: `Ha, I'm not a moderator` - well, that explains a lot ;). Thanks a lot once again.